# Video Player Delay

Tags: android-studio, android-tv

I am new adroid studio, ı want to use this program at android tv (mi boxs) and ı try to when ı press to button the video play and get in to the loop.Everting okey but I have a jumping problem with video player. I preessed to button after video started first second and jumped third second. I shared my code, How can i fix that problem. Thank you.

```
public class stActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private VideoView videoBG;
    MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    int mCurrentVideoPosition;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_st);
        videoBG = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView8);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.kb);
        videoBG.setVideoURI(uri);

        videoBG.start();

        videoBG.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                mMediaPlayer = mediaPlayer;
                mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);

                if (mCurrentVideoPosition != 0) {

                    mMediaPlayer.seekTo(mCurrentVideoPosition);
                    mMediaPlayer.start();
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                }


            }
        });
    }
    }
```